# Find solutions of $F(x)=\frac32 F\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-equations

I need to construct a continuous function $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with $F(0)=0$ and $F(x)=\frac32 F\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-1\right)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

I found $F(x)\equiv0$ is a solution. Moreover, if F is a polynomial, I could prove that $F$ must be zero function. My question is: Is there another such function?

I think it must be have, but I could not construct them.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around.

Putting $x^3$ for $x$,
this becomes
$2f(x^3) = 3f(x^2-1)
$.

As Clever Sea wrote,
$f$ can't be a polynomial
since, if the polynomial
is of degree $n$,
the left side is of
degree $3n$
and the right is of degree
$2n$.

Putting $x = -1$,
$2f(-1) = 3f(0) = 0$
so $f(-1) = 0$.

Putting $x = 1$,
$2f(1) = 3f(0) = 0$
so $f(1) = 0$.

If $x_0$ is the real root of
$x^3 = x^2-1$,
then $f(x_0) = 0$
otherwise $f$
would not be continuous at $x_0$.

Putting $-x$ for $x$,
$f(-x^3) = f(x^2-1)
=f(x^3)
$
so $f$ is an even function.

$x^3$ is increasing for all $x \ne 0$
and
$x^2-1$
is decreasing for $x < 0$.

If $f(a) \ne 0$,
there will be a 
neighborhood of $a$
where $f$ is of constant sign.

It's late,
and I don't see how to proceed from here,
so I hope this will be of use
to others.

Bye.